# how can I resize my Ubuntu partitions

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, gparted

I installed Ubuntu16.04.1 on an external hard disk, with win7 on the internal hard disk. The grub file is on the external drive.

The external drive is 1TB. and I used the last 50 GB for Ubuntu. Now I want to extend the Ubuntu partitions, for 50GB is not enough.

I tried gparted with a bootable USB. It didn't work. the screenshot is as following,
[image: screenshot of the partitions]

How can I increase the size of sdb9? Now I can only decrease the size. Can't expand dev/sdb2 or dev/sdb7 either.

Thank you!

update
[image: moved the sdb2 to the left of unallocated disk] Now I am going to move the boot partition.

Comment: You need to move the extended partition sdb2 (contains sdb9) all the way to the left, then increase that extended partition and finally the contained partitions. PS - your swap is absurd, a waste of space. With 8GB RAM or more you hardly need 2GB.

Comment: move the extended partition sdb2 (contains sdb9) all the way to the left... how to do that?
Yes, I have 8GB RAM. I thought swap size is just the double of RAM size, after reading some reference on the internet. :(

Comment: You do that with GParted, of course. It's actually the same option (resize/move). The informations you've been reading about swap are quite outdated.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Good suggestions! You should post an answer.

Comment: Your little key icons show mounted partitions, you need to use a live flash or DVD version so partitions are not mounted. Even live installer mounts swap you you may need to swap off or unmount swap with live installer. Is sdb7 a /boot partition? That is not normally used with desktop installs unless also full drive LVM with encryption.

Comment: @oldfred Yes, sdb7 is /boot. I am a beginner. :(

Comment: @CelticWarrior I have resized the partitions successfully. Thank you! I am afraied that moving boot partition would cause some error before. Luckily, nothing happened.

Comment: @oldfred Thank you. Finally, All partitions were resized.